# How do I hide a custom "loading" view once the data in my tableView has loaded?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've placed an animated view above my `tableView` in Interface Builder, and right now the view remains visible after the data in my `tableView` loads. I simply want to hide the animated view once any/all of the `tableView` data loads. The solution must be in objective-c for this project.

** I know about `activityIndicatorView` but chose not to use it for no particular reason. I just liked the look of the animated view more. If there is a simpler solution using `activityIndicatorView` I'd be happy to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hide or remove the animated view where you reload the table view. Where would you stop the activityIndicatorView animation if you use it?

Comment: It looks like I was reloading the table view in multiple areas so that's what was causing the indicator to stay visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `willDisplayCell` method of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Check if the index path is the index path of the last row in the table view, and if it is, hide the view you want to hide.
}
```

Note: This method will be called whenever the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

What takes time is downloading data from your API not populating table view. You can safely hide your animated view right after you call reloadData method. If I didn't understand the question well give us more info.